# How to create a pivot table with xssf using apache poi?

Tags: java, csv

I have a requirement where i need the pivot table in following manner:

[image]

I needed the output in the above manner, but I'm  getting in the following manner:

[image]

I have written the code in following manner:

```
pivotTable.addReportFilter( 12 );
pivotTable.addReportFilter( 13 );
pivotTable.addRowLabel( 11 );
pivotTable.addDataColumn( 15, true );
pivotTable.addColumnLabel( DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 15 );
```

How to get the column filter as required??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the apache-poi from 3.14 to 4.1.0, where 4.1.x version provides  the method addColLabel(columnIndex). Using addColLabel(columnIndex) allows to select particular column as column fields for the pivot table creation.

Code:

```
            pivotTable.addReportFilter( 12 );
            pivotTable.addReportFilter( 13 );
            pivotTable.addRowLabel( 11 );
            pivotTable.addColLabel( 0 );
            pivotTable.addColumnLabel( DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 15 );
```